# Azure ML Pipeline - Error: Message: "Missing data for required field". Path: "environment". value: "null"

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to create a pipeline with Python SDK v2 in Azure Machine Learning Studio. Been stuck on this error for many.. MANY.. hours now, so now I am reaching out.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have been following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk

My setup is very similar, but I split "data_prep" into two separate steps, and I am using a custom ml model.

How the pipeline is defined:

`

```
# the dsl decorator tells the sdk that we are defining an Azure ML pipeline
from azure.ai.ml import dsl, Input, Output
import pathlib
import os


@dsl.pipeline(
    compute=cpu_compute_target,
    description="Car predict pipeline",
)
def car_predict_pipeline(
    pipeline_job_data_input,
    pipeline_job_registered_model_name,
):
    # using data_prep_function like a python call with its own inputs
    data_prep_job = data_prep_component(
        data=pipeline_job_data_input,
    )

    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print(os.path.realpath(str(pipeline_job_data_input)))
    print(os.path.realpath(str(data_prep_job.outputs.prepared_data)))

    print('-----------------------------------------------')

    train_test_split_job = traintestsplit_component(
        prepared_data=data_prep_job.outputs.prepared_data
    )

    # using train_func like a python call with its own inputs
    train_job = train_component(
        train_data=train_test_split_job.outputs.train_data,  # note: using outputs from previous step
        test_data=train_test_split_job.outputs.test_data,  # note: using outputs from previous step
        registered_model_name=pipeline_job_registered_model_name,
    )

    # a pipeline returns a dictionary of outputs
    # keys will code for the pipeline output identifier
    return {
        # "pipeline_job_train_data": train_job.outputs.train_data,
        # "pipeline_job_test_data": train_job.outputs.test_data,
        "pipeline_job_model": train_job.outputs.model
    }
```

`
I managed to run every single component successfully, in order, via the command line and produced a trained model. Ergo the components and data works fine, but the pipeline won't run.

I can provide additional info, but I am not sure what is needed and I do not want to clutter the post.

I have tried googling. I have tried comparing the tutorial pipeline with my own. I have tried using print statements to isolate the issue. Nothing has worked so far. Nothing that I have done has changed the error either, it's the same error no matter what.

**Edit:**

Some additional info about my environment:

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment

custom_env_name = "pipeline_test_environment_pricepredict_model"

pipeline_job_env = Environment(
    name=custom_env_name,
    description="Environment for testing out Jeppes model in pipeline building",
    conda_file=os.path.join(dependencies_dir, "conda.yml"),
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-ubuntu18.04:latest",
    version="1.0",
)
pipeline_job_env = ml_client.environments.create_or_update(pipeline_job_env)

print(
    f"Environment with name {pipeline_job_env.name} is registered to workspace, the environment version is {pipeline_job_env.version}"
)
```

[Build status of environment. It had already run successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ppbq.png)

Answer (score 0):

In azure machine learning studio, when the application was running and model was deployed we have the default options to get the curated environments or custom environments. If the environment was created based on the existing deployment, we need to check with the build was successful or not.

[image]

Until we get the success in the deployment, we cannot get the environment variables noted into the program and we cannot retrieve the variables through the code block.

[image]

Select the environment need to be used.

[image]

[image]

Choose the existing version created.

[image]

We will get the mount location details and the docker file if creating using the docker and conda environment.

[image]

The environment and up and running successfully. If the case is running, then using the asset ID or the mount details we can retrieve the environment variables information.

```
/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/workspace-name/code/files/docker/Dockerfile
```

[image]

Comment: I tried following your steps here, but nothing changed. The environment build was successful as well.

Comment: Once check the path of the data asserts and replace that with the accurate file path. It is seeking the docker files path in './files' location.